# Use Javascript and if/else statements in blogger to hide certain elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, blogger

I have a blog on blogger and I want to use JS to hide items and show others according to certain conditions I use in if/else statements. 
Here is the code

```
<div id="Left-Ads-Sticky-1024-768" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; position: absolute;">
    Left-Ads-Sticky-1024-768
  </div>
  <div id="Left-Ads-Sticky-1280-800" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; position: absolute;">
    Left-Ads-Sticky-1280-800
  </div>
  <div id="Left-Ads-Sticky-1366-768" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; position: absolute;">
    Left-Ads-Sticky-1366-768
  </div>
  <script language="JavaScript">
    var W=screen.width; var H=screen.hieght;
    if (W==1366) &amp;&amp; (H==768))
    {
        document.getElementById("Left-Ads-Sticky-1024-768").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("Left-Ads-Sticky-1280-800").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
    else 
    { 
        document.getElementById("Left-Ads-Sticky-1366-768").style.display = "inline";
    } 
  </script>
```

please help me get it done.
Thanks.

Comment: For starters you don't want `&amp;&amp;` in the middle of your Javascript.  Also, do you really want to be checking for an exact height and width?  It would be extremely rare for that condition to occur in a regular browser.

Comment: what is screen?..Are you assuming it a pre defined object which will help to get visible height/width or you have created yourself?

Comment: @Rakesh_Kumar - `screen` is a built-in object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.screen

Comment: @jfriend00 ok I will edit the $amp; and add <!-- and //--> in the script.

Comment: if you are trying to do 'and' in an if statement you need to be using `&&`

Comment: I am trying to detect the screen width and height then according to them I want to display some elements and hide other.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks.. :) I dint know that..Poor me..

Comment: abdallah, see this page http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/Using-media-queries-in-JavaScript-AbsurdJS-edition

if you are familiar with @media for css, this is javascripts method.

Comment: You have a typo ('height'), so the condition will never be met.  Do you need both conditions to be met?  Maybe `||` would be better.  Also, do you mean `==`, or should it be `>`?  And missing an opening `(` in your `if` statement.

Comment: @adamJosephLooze Thanks but I am not familiar with it

Comment: @media in css detects a browsers resolution.  but not exact resolution.  it detects if the resolution is at least ---.  for example,

`@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) { /* STYLES GO HERE */ }`

This would only apply the css styles in "STYLES GO HERE" to a device with at least a resolution of 768 and max resolution of 1024.  (Which is an ipad for example)

Javascript has this as well, using that link above

Comment: @sideroxylon I have done it with || and didn't work and corrected if statement as well

Comment: @adamjosephlooze Should i use these codes inside <script> tags ??

Comment: I don't think your `if` statement makes sense.  Try without the `else` and just add the third line of code to the `if` statement. As it is now, if the condition is met the smaller ads would be hidden - and that's all.  The larger ads will only be shown if the condition is not met (and so will the smaller ads).

Comment: no.  they wont work.  they are for css.  check out absurdjs.  it is a javascript library with that function.

Comment: @sideroxylon this is the new code here
<br/>
script language="JavaScript">
  <!--
  var W=screen.width; var H=screen.hieght;
  if ((W>=1366) && (H>=768))
  {
   document.getElementById("Left-Ads-Sticky-1366-768").style.display = "inline";
   document.getElementById("Left-Ads-Sticky-1024-768").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("Left-Ads-Sticky-1280-800").style.display = "none";
        }
  //-->
      </script>

Comment: your script wont work.. trust me.  and it you got it, it wouldnt be worth it.  read up on absurdjs, (its pretty simple after u understand how it works) and download and include that js file in your library, then you can input its media functions anywhere you want on any of your pages.  ez

Comment: You still have the typo in `H=screen.height` - the condition will never trigger.

Comment: @sideroxylon sorry I corrected it but didn't trigger :(

Comment: abdallah.  try my answer.

Comment: I tested this: `<script>
var W=screen.width; 
var H=screen.height; 
if ((W>=1366) && (H>=768)) 
{ alert('hello'); 
}
</script>` - and it works.

Comment: @sideroxylon I know It works but I want the hiding method to work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy and paste this into your browser.  It will detect your resolution and alert depending on if `max-width: 300px` is true or false. (if, else)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var mq = window.matchMedia('all and (max-width: 300px)');
if(mq.matches) {
    alert("the width of browser is more then 300px");
} else {
    alert("the width of browser is less then 300px");
}
});
```

You can paste your own code where the alerts are, like so

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var mq = window.matchMedia('all and (max-width: 1366px)'); // Your desired max resolution goes here. (you can change this to min-width)
if(mq.matches) {
    document.getElementById("Left-Ads-Sticky-1024-768").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("Left-Ads-Sticky-1280-800").style.visibility = "hidden";
} else {
    document.getElementById("Left-Ads-Sticky-1366-768").style.display = "inline";
}
});
```

UPDATE: minify version

```
$(document).ready(function(){var e=window.matchMedia("all and (max-width: 1366px)");e.matches?(document.getElementById("Left-Ads-Sticky-1024-768").style.visibility="hidden",document.getElementById("Left-Ads-Sticky-1280-800").style.visibility="hidden"):document.getElementById("Left-Ads-Sticky-1366-768").style.display="inline"});
```

Comment: I have used it and it showed this : the width of browser is less then 700px but I have no clew what did it detect

Comment: it detected your browser width.  i forgot to change the alert..  but do you understand how javascript works.  do you understand how if, else statements and alerts work?

Try pasting the below code.  it is exactly what you were trying to do.

So the javascript is saying, (for the bottom code on my answer) if browser width is less than 1366, do this.  else (if it isnt) do this.

does that make sense?

Comment: It worked and the divs are hidden :) Thanks so much but there is a small problem ... I want them to disappear from the inspect element page as well!

Comment: Yeah I know how it works and Now I can play with it to what I want :)

Comment: Is that on a different url page?  if so, copy and paste that code in the other pages, and change the `document.getElementById` to the correct ones for the pages.

Comment: good i am glad, if you are happy with my answer, could you please chose it as correct.  and if you have any more questions, dont hesitate to ask.

Comment: the last thing I want to do is to hide the elements entirely from the source code of the page ... like it didn't exist .. do you understand me?

Comment: i dont fully understand no.  like if a person right clicks on the browser and clicks "examine source code" or "inspect element" you want it to not show up?

Comment: yes I want only the code I shown in if/else statement to be shown in inspect element or source code page.. 
is that possible in blogger ?

Comment: That is not possible because javascript is client side, just like html and css.  It is translated on everyone's browser, thus it will always be viewable.  But you could copy that javascript and put it into a seperate javascript.js file, then include the javascript file where you need it.  `<script src="myJavaScriptFile.js"></script>`

It will add an extra step to the potential viewer.

Comment: You could minify your javascript.  See the update on my answer.  Copy and paste that.  it is the same code, just without whitespace. That would make it more difficult to decipher by the naked eye.  Check out http://javascript-minifier.com/ to minify your javascripts (remove whitespace), it will all still be fully functional.  (actually it will improve loading speed by a fraction of a millasecond.

Comment: OK no problem, but I want it instead of detecting the resolution of the screen itself I want it to detect the browser width and height.
is that possible and how ?

Comment: You want height , and width?  and that does detect the resolution of your browser.  that is all it can do because it is only interacting with your browser.  i would recomend not height and width.  the chances of them being exact are slim.  and with reduced width, comes reduced height.. thus one is only necessary.

Comment: I want to get the browser's height and width not the screen.

Comment: Check out this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/L0v5ftrd/
press 'try it' and then resize the lower right window and press 'try it' again'  this gets the browsers height and width and stores them into variables.  From here you can take those variables, and say `if((w==1366) && (h==768)){ alert("true"); }else{ alert("false"); }` and change the alerts to your desired code

Comment: Your welcome :)  I am glad you got this figured out.  Any more questions, feel free.  Good luck

Comment: there is one more :D 
I want this code window.matchMedia('all and (min-width: 1366px)'); to use the jsfiddle so I can get the browser resolution

Comment: Also I want to combine many conditions here : ('all and (min-width: 1366px)') .. as I have multiple screen resolutions

Comment: ?? please last help so I can do it as i am not familiar with absurdjs

Comment: I went to bed after i said good luck, feel free to email me adam.ncmich.edu@gmail.com and i will assist you further.  i want to keep chatter to a minimum here.